# How do I move the "Show Applications" icon in Ubuntu Dock?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Ubuntu 17.10 introduces the GNOME Shell with the [Ubuntu Dock](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock) (based on [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) GNOME Shell extension) and it allows you to put the Dock on the bottom of the desktop:

[image: Ubuntu 17.10 Dock on the bottom of the desktop]

However, there is no easy way to move the *Show Applications* icon (shown on the right) to the left of the Dock. There is no such setting in GNOME Control Center. There is already a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1713621) filed, but does anybody know any workaround until it gets fixed by Ubuntu Dock developers?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The following command will work for the current user:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true
```

Is the command-line equivalent to dconf-editor GUI.

To make it persistent system-wide, run these commands as root:

```sh
echo "show-apps-at-top=true" >> /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-dock.gschema.override
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Comment: It seems only the first command is enough if you want to make the change for your user-account instead of changing it system-wide.

Comment: Agreed.  I ran only the first command and it was persistent across reboots.

Answer (score 55):

If you don't like to run command then open **dconf-editor** (by simply click show applications icon and search *dconf*) then go to

**org > gnome > shell > extensions > dash-to-dock**

Then search for the **show-apps-at-top** and make it **on**

See screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Nice! But I think dconf-Editor is not being shipped with Ubuntu 17.10 by default. You might want to add the installation process i.e. `sudo apt install dconf-editor` to make your answer more complete.

Comment: @pomsky When I updated my System from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 it is installed by default. May be it doesn't comes with the latest version i.e. with 17.10.

Comment: Is Dash to Dock still the Ubuntu Dock if I installed Dash to Dock over it?

Comment: Is there a way to remove the 'Show applications' tool tip on hover? Now i've moved to the left the tooltip appears over the icons to the right of the icon. The application icons show the tooltip above.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Thank you, worked for me too with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS!

Comment: Still works in 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove it with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-show-apps-button false
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a way but the dock will be like in middle.

- Download and install gnome-tweaks.
- Go to any browser and go to extensions.gnome.org
- Click on *click here to install browser extension*.
- Go ahead and install it.
- After it's done again go to extensions.gnome.org
- Search for dash to dock.
- Click it and toggle its ON position.
- Go to tweaks app (search for it in app menu)
- Go to extensions tab.
- Go to dash to dock.
- Toggle it on (if not already on).
- Click the Gear icon on the right side dash to dock option. Then there will be option for changing the place of launcher in **LAUNCHERS** tab
- Tick mark the **Move the application button at the beginning of dock** option